# Declare variable inline with template class definition

Tags: c++

I have a linked list structure like this:

```
template<class T>
class LinkedList {
private:

    template<class U>
    struct Node {
        U data;
        Node<U> *link;
    };

    Node<T> *head;
};
```

What I'd ideally like to do is merge the inner class definition with the declaration of `head`, as in:

```
// Is something like this possible?
template<class U>
struct Node {
    U data;
    Node<U> *link;
} head; // Put head right here somehow, while also specifying the type parameter.
```

since the whole point of creating the `Node<U>` structure is to define `head`. Is it possible to tie these two together?

Comment: Not really; BTW, why is `Node` a template? Why not just `struct Node { T data; Node *link; };`?

Comment: Don't put variable declarations at the same place as a struct/class definition. That just makes your code less readable.

Comment: Hmm, yeah I can see that. Thanks interjay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just keep placeholder `T` and remove unnecessary `U`:

```
template<class T>
class LinkedList {
private:

    struct Node {
        T data;
        Node *link;
    };

    Node *head;
};
```

Comment: Ah, perfect. I figured I was making some fundamental mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can, for whatever reason you want to, join them together. You just have to remove the redundant `template<class U>`.

```
template<class T>
class LinkedList {
private:
    struct Node {
        T data;
        Node* link;
    }* head;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer your first example, but you don't need two template parameters like you have there.

```
template<class T>
class LinkedList {
private:
    struct Node {
        T data;
        Node *link;
    };

    Node *head;
};
```

I think this is much cleaner than your second example. For instance you can now write `search` and `insert` functions on your `LinkedList` class. With your other example they would have to be external functions.